# CPU soft lockup before instalation

Tags: system-installation, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on Acer nitro 5 Ryzen 5 2500U with Vega8 mobile and Radeon RX 560X. Unfortunately when I click *Install Ubuntu* or *Try Without Installing* it shows some error messages.

Also tried installing Linux Mint 19 but it only works in compatibility mode and after installing the same problem occurs.

Tried `nouveau.modeset=0` with no result.

I'm posting an image instead of code because I can't dump the console since it's all locked up.

[image: boot messages photo]